# Dynamic String Splitting in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, string, random

I need to achieve the following:

```
Dim lstrSource as String = "Hello-Hi"
```

To get "Hi" in the source, we will apply, `lstrSource.Split("-")(1)`.

But, my source string will change every time, and the splitting operation instruction also user will enter.

So, I am trying to achieve something like this.

```
Dim lstrSpiltInstn as String = "Split("-")(1)"
```

`lstrSource.lstrSplitInstn` => this need return "Hi"

Will it be possible or are there any other ways to achieve this.

Comment: `lstrSource.Split("-")(0)` will return `Hello` **not** `Hi`.

Comment: The delimiter and the array index are already variables. You just need to store both of them.

Answer (score 2):

"Hi" is the second token, not the first. Apart from that, the parameter should be the delimiter and the index, not the method itself.

So you could use this method:

```
Public Shared Function SplitByGetAt(input As String, delimiter As String, index As Int32, options As StringSplitOptions) As String
    If input Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("input")
    If delimiter Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("delimiter")
    If delimiter.Length = 0 Then Throw New ArgumentException("Delimiter must be specified", "delimiter")
    If index < 0 Then Throw New ArgumentException("Index must be equal or greater than 0", "index")

    Dim tokens = input.Split({delimiter}, options)
    If index >= tokens.Length Then Return Nothing
    Return tokens(index)
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim lstrSource as String = "Hello-Hi"
Dim result As String = SplitByGetAt(lstrSource, "-", 1, StringSplitOptions.None)
' Result: Hi
```

If you want to make it an extension method:

```
Public Module MyExtensions
    <Extension()>
    Public Function SplitByGetAt(input As String, delimiter As String, index As Int32, options As StringSplitOptions) As String
        If input Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("input")
        If delimiter Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("delimiter")
        If delimiter.Length = 0 Then Throw New ArgumentException("Delimiter must be specified", "delimiter")
        If index < 0 Then Throw New ArgumentException("Index must be greater than 0", "index")

        Dim tokens = input.Split({delimiter}, options)
        If index >= tokens.Length Then Return Nothing
        Return tokens(index)
    End Function
End Module
```

Now you can use it in this way:

```
lstrSource.SplitByGetAt("-", 1, StringSplitOptions.None)
```